# Does 12 V DC to +6 VDC and -6VDC with discrete components require conversion to AC?

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, dc, dc-dc-converter, voltage-divider

I have a 12 volt battery and want to power a 741 Op Amp, but that requires + and - voltage supplies. Is there a more efficient way to give a + and - supply to the op amp from the battery without converting to AC first.

By converting to AC first I mean:

- DC Battery->
- AC Inverter->
- Transformer:Primary Two Tap, Secondary Center Tap:Three Tap with center Tap Grounded->
- DC Rectify Top and Bottom Tap
- ~ +6 V Top and ~ -6V Bottom

[image]

Comment: Whatever method chosen you will have poor results using a 741. Of course if you want a vintage circuit circa 1963 then a 741 is perfect.

Comment: The actual circuit would be helpful, the op amp may not need a negative rail, and as a cheap alternative if the power consumed by the circuit is not high, you can use an op amp to act as a virtual ground at half supply.

Comment: You write "but that requires + and - voltage supplies" - but this is not true. Your opamp does not have a ground connection. It does not "know" if you're powering it with +6/-6, +9/-3, +1/-11, etc. - or even +12/-0. All it "sees" is the difference.

Comment: The easiest approach is to define the battery terminals as +6V and -6V, and to create a voltage halfway between them (e.g. with two resistors and a buffer) called 0V. No AC required.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks, that's what I ended up doing except with a capacitors divider instead of resistor divider!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires conversion to AC, but not necessarily a transformer. Maybe an inductor or capacitors will work fine, depending on the current requirements.

The easiest thing is to buy a DC-DC converter module with an isolated output or +/- output. You can also use a switchmode power supply chip as an inverting boost converter with only a single inductor. In keeping with your retro-space-age \$\mu A741\$ theme, you could use an [MC34063](https://www.onsemi.cn/PowerSolutions/document/MC34063A-D.PDF). That could give you +/-12V

Alternatively, you could split the 12V into +6V/-6V. The easiest way to do that is to use a rail-splitter IC such as the [TLE2426](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tle2426.pdf?&ts=1590155525120). The disadvantage of that is that you no longer have ground-referenced inputs and outputs relative to the +12V/0V supply. Whether that's an issue or not depends on your application. You could also have noise issues if the +12V supply is not clean (for example, if it's a vehicle +12V supply).

Comment: Thanks for selecting this answer and welcome! You may wish to deselect this answer for 24 hours or so and see if a better answer comes along, as selecting an answer is a slight disincentive for others to work on it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. The only reason I picked the 741 is because it's used in my textbook, but I guess all the recommended ICs are outdated now. I'll look for new chips. This helps a lot.